# get an unknown amount of numbers from the user and get the average of these numbers with using dynamically allocated memory to store the values

Tags: c++, c

I need to write a code that gets an unknown amount of numbers from the user and get the average of these numbers with using dynamically allocated memory to store the values, but I could write it in C++ and it must be C.How can I convert it in C language?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Get the number of inputs"<<endl;
    cin>>n; // input total number of elements
    int* a = new int[n]; //creating a dynamic array
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    double* average=new double;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        *average+=a[i]; //storing sum
    }
    *average=*average/n*1.0; // calculating average
    cout<<"average of all numbers is "<<*average<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is all i can do,but it still doesn`t compile.there are two error at line 17 and 19.(I have to use dynamically allocated memory)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Get the number of inputs:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n); // input total number of elements
    int* a[n]; //creating a dynamic array
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
       
        
    }
    double* average=malloc(double*);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        *average+=a[i]; //storing sum
    }
    *average=*average/n*1.0; // calculating average
   printf("average of all numbers is:%lf",average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need dynamic allocation to make this calculation, at all. This simple calculation is a simple mathematical formula that can be calculated without even storing each value read. If you have to use dynamic allocation, the basics are explained in every C textbook. Is there something in your C textbook's explanation of dynamic memory allocation that's unclear to you?

Comment: If you need to write a program in C then you first need to *learn* C. There are many available books, online-tutorials and classes (both online and offline).

Comment: just add them up while the user enters them. The array is not needed and the user cannot possibly tell the difference

Comment: And as mentioned you don't even need any dynamic allocation for the array `a`. And even less need for `average`.

Comment: If you allocate for `average` dynamically, why don't you use dynamic allocation for `n`?

Comment: Also, Include library header `#include <stdlib.h>`.
Remove `&` in statement ` scanf("%d",&a[i]);`
And try to optimise the Code. Use of Normal variables will do the trick unless the Problem statement requires use of Pointers

Comment: @Raky If you want to use `scanf("%d",a[i]);`, initialization of each `a[i]` is required before `scanf`.

Comment: @MikeCAT, Yes what you say is correct. I missed the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should create an array of `int`, not `int*`.
- You should use `sizeof` to calculate the size to allocate via `malloc()`.
- You have to initialize buffer allocated via `malloc()` before using its value for calculation. Otherwise, *undefined behavior* is invoked.
- You should add `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `malloc()`.
- You should dereference `average` to print the buffer via `printf()`. Otherwise, *undefined behavior* is invoked for passing data having wrong type.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
/* add #include */
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Get the number of inputs:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n); // input total number of elements
    /* create array of int, not int* */
    int a[n]; //creating a dynamic array
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
       
        
    }
    /* calculate size to allocate via sizeof */
    double* average=malloc(sizeof(*average));
    /* check if allocation succeeded */
    if (average == NULL) return 1;
    /* initialize the buffer */
    *average = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        *average+=a[i]; //storing sum
    }
    *average=*average/n*1.0; // calculating average
    /* dereference average before printing */
    printf("average of all numbers is:%lf",*average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output must be average of the given numbers, but i get 0.000000.

Comment: @HamzaÇoban Try updated code. If it also doesn't work, change `%lf` to `%f` because some old compilers may not support `%lf` in `printf()`.

Comment: Good Code and Good Explanation. Upvoted you @MikeCAT